# NSFetchedResultsController Error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 1 in section at index 0' 

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an app using tableview and NSFetchedResultsController. I am getting the error:

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 1 in section at index 0'
```

... from the code below. `selectedevents` is an array whose count is equal to that of objects in fetched results controller.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[self.selectedEvents count]; i++) {
    CustomDictionary *dic=[selectedEvents objectAtIndex:i];
    if (dic.isSelected) {
        Event *evt=[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        [array addObject:evt];
    }
}
for (Event *evt in array) {
    [context deleteObject:evt];
}
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Comment: Do you have entries  in dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the code below "selectedevents" is
>   an array whose count is equal to that
>   of objects in fetched results
>   controller.

but

> error says that 'no object at index 1
>   in section at index 0' your fetched
>   result controller may have multiple
>   sections.

Also, code should be:

```
NSManagedObject *evt=[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
```

...not:

```
Event *evt=[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to base another array on `[NSFetchedResultController fetchedObjects]` is dangerous because the fetched results controller is always automatically updating itself. Your problem is caused by this loop:

```
   for (int i=0; i<[self.selectedEvents count]; i++) { 
        CustomDictionary *dic=[selectedEvents objectAtIndex:i];
        if (dic.isSelected) {
            Event *evt=[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            [array addObject:evt];
        }
    }
```

... looping twice when you only have one object returnable by `[NSFetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:]`. That is probably caused by `selectedEvents` being set when `fetchedObjects` has two or more elements and then one is deleted without updating `selectedEvents` for the new count. When you try to loop over the rows, you go at least one to far and get the exception.

Changing the for-loop to index directly on `fetchedObjects`:

```
for (int i=0; i<[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]; i++)
```

... will solve the immediate problem but your code will always be fragile if you rely on trying to sync the `selectedEvents` array with the fetched results controller.